# Hipster stack (Yeoman + Maven + Spring) Error

Tags: spring, yeoman, yeoman-generator, jhipster

When I tried to generate with `yo jhipster` on Windows 7 32 bits machine, I got the below error:

> bower json3#~3.2.5                    progress received 3.7MB of 4.9MB
>   downloaded, 75%   libjpeg-62.dll: downloading [===================]
>   100% 0.0s
>
> ? pre-build test failed, compiling from source...
>
> d:\Self_jhipster\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\jpegtran-bin\
>   lib\check.js:19
>                           throw new Error('building is not supported on ' + process.platform);
>
> ```
>                           ^ Error: building is not supported on win32
>
> at d:\Self_jhipster\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\jpegtran-bin\lib\check.js:19:10
> ```

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the author of http://jhipster.github.io/ which is the generator your are referring to.

I have found your problem, it is indeed a bug in jpegtran-bin. I have updated all the dependencies in Grunt.js, and it should now work fine on Windows.

This will be commited in the next release (0.2.1), which should be out in a few hours.

You can also submit a bug at https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues

Comment: Release 0.2.1 looks good in Windows 32 bits. BTW, if we use Compass, `grunt server` should be run to compile css before we first time run `mvn jetty:run`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't have Windows so it's hard for me to test! I'll have a look at Compass.

Answer (score 1):

After google with more correct keywords, the solution from https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-imagemin/issues/109 works for me.

1. In application's package.json, add `"jpegtran-bin": "0.2.0"` before
   the reference for `imagemin`,
2. Remove node_module folder locally.
3. Run `npm install` again.